# how to update thumbnails preview of android gallery after image edited

Tags: android, android-gallery

possible duplicate

[Refreshing the thumbnail using MediaScanner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7805527/760489)

I have a problem regarding the update of thumbnails in the android in built-in gallery. Actually I have opened, edited and saved the image which was selected in the gallery.

I open leave the gallery and open the gallery again, then the thumbnail for that image is not updated. However, I pick the image, it is the edited version indeed.

Does anybody have solution about this? I have search but I'm getting the answer about refreshing the gallery using `sendBroadcast()`, which does not seem to update the image previews.

Edit

I don't want to delete the existing file because suppose user want to save file with different name then that file did not affected

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805527/refreshing-the-thumbnail-using-mediascanner

Comment: @Pratik Excuse me, have you got an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions.

- Try  [getThumbnail](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html#getThumbnail%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20long,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29). From the javadoc, I would expect it to regenerate an up-to-date thumbnail.
- If that doesn't update the thumbnail, try deleting the thumbnail.

Comment: I am open the android inbuilt gallery using Intent not programmatically create the gallery

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this problem, before you request a new thumbnail you need to delete old one. Use MediaStore and ContentResolver for this

```
private static void removeThumbnails(ContentResolver contentResolver, long photoId) {
Cursor thumbnails = contentResolver.query(Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(photoId)}, null);
for (thumbnails.moveToFirst(); !thumbnails.isAfterLast(); thumbnails.moveToNext()) {

    long thumbnailId = thumbnails.getLong(thumbnails.getColumnIndex(Thumbnails._ID));
    String path = thumbnails.getString(thumbnails.getColumnIndex(Thumbnails.DATA));
    File file = new File(path);
    if (file.delete()) {

        contentResolver.delete(Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Thumbnails._ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(thumbnailId)});

    }

}
```

You can get photoId from its URI, to get URI from file name just create File and parse URI from it

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```